# How to gather all Robot Framework Globals

Tags: global-variables, robotframework

Is there a command that can be run like pythons globals() in robot framework that is a dict or list of all globals it knows about? I am trying to run parts of robot code as remote executions, however I need to pass globals to the remote server. I do not know in advance what globals to pass.

I will need to pass them as **args

```
${items} =    Remote Keyword     &{ALL_SUITE_GLOBALS}
```

Thanks you.

Comment: Hey, that's interesting question! I can't answer but I'm really curious what the others will suggest. As I understand `Log Variables` doesn't provide what you need.

Comment: Do you need a list of only global variables? You can get a list of all variables, but I don't think there's a way to get a list of only global variables.

Comment: All variables wouldn't hurt... but I need them and their values so that remote code copy of local code can execute and use the same globals. For instance ${user} and ${user_password} might be set from `robot -v` and be needed at the remote location

Answer (score 1):

According to Robot framework documentation we can set global variables from command line using the option --variable.

I think this can be achieved using **ANT** for which u need to configure build.xml.
You have to add **robotant** library in your lib folder

Create **build.properties** file which contains variables which you want to use globally.

Example :

```
SERVER_IP = X.X.X.X
SERVER_PORT = 9090
```

Add these variables in build.xml file

```
<robotant>
    <arg line="--variable  SERVER_IP:${SERVER_IP}" />
    <arg line="--variable  SERVER_PORT:${SERVER_PORT}" />
</robotant>
```

Now you can use these variables globally in your program.

Comment: This is interesting, though, I don't think this is accomplishing what I need. I have a remote robot server configured. That locally has the same robot code base as my local robot. I want to be able to run elements of my robot code remotely, there are a FEW command line -v ${vars} set but the majority of the globals I need are from the *** Variables *** section of robot libraries or variable files. I need ALL globals passed over not just command line.